# How can I be notified that window is activated?

Tags: c++, events, embedded, windows-mobile

I am developing an application in eVC++. In MFC OnInitDialog() indicates that your page is initializing. I want an event notifies me every time my page is activated. What is that event?

Comment: You can override the CPropertyPage's OnSetActive() method.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the message [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**edit:**

or [WM_ACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

or override the method [OnSetActive()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5zd196y3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: there is no WM_SETFOCUS in c++ wizard list

Comment: there is no WM_ACTIVATE in c++ wizard list

Comment: do you have the right class selected in the class wizard? I just verified, I do get that message for CDialog derived classes.

Comment: try adding it manually:
add "ON_WM_SETFOCUS()" to your messsage map, and use "afx_msg void OnSetFocus(CWnd* pOldWnd);". don't forget to call the base classes method.

Comment: my class is derived from CPropertyPage

Comment: I added it to .CPP -> `BOOL CChequePage::OnSetActive() 
{
 MsgBox( m_hWnd, _T("aaa"), B_OK, I_ERROR );
 return CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
}` and `BOOL OnSetActive();` to .h but it does not work. what should i do?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure at this point. As far as I can tell, the documentation says that OnSetActive() is what you should need =/

Comment: There is now an ON_WM_SETFOCUS and a corresponding OnSetFocus: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx1ea34a.aspx and ON_WM_SETFOCUS is defined in the framework's afxmsg_.h

Answer (score 1):

By page what do you mean. If you are talking about windows there is function called
**CWnd::OnActivate** in MFC.

Comment: is it applicable for Windows Mobile applications?